# Cannot find symbol method loadUrl(String)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. When I try to make this project it throws me the error:

`Cannot find symbol method loadUrl(String)` in the `MainActivity.java`.

The `loadUrl` is highlighted in red. I've made a folder assets in the main and added www folder in the assests folder.

```
package com.rmworks.digitalindia;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a **WebView** object like this:

In your `layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Then in `MainActivity.java` use this:

```
WebView webViewer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Obviously you have to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Read this [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) 
for a better explanation

If you want to use `super.loadUrl(String)` you have to import `org.apache.cordova.*`, read this [PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)