# Getting webview to load spinner XML values

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a app in Android Studio where you have defined URLs in the spinner. And when you choose a item in the spinner it should load the URL into spinner.

I have gotten some help with this, but now I face another problem: I'm getting:

> cannot resolve symbol method loadUrl java.lang.strin

My XML code:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Obligatorisk1</string>
   <string-array name="spinner">
    <item value="http://www.vg.no">VG</item>
    <item value="http://www.dagbladet.no">Dagbladet</item>
    <item value="http://www.nettavisen.no">Nettavisen</item>
</string-array>
<string name="omAppen">Om Appen</string>
<string name="title_activity_main2">Om Appen</string>
```

My main activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

private Button omAppenKnapp;
Spinner spinner;
WebView wb1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    wb1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wb1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
R.array.spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
int i, long l) {

            String urlName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            String urlValue = "http://www.google.com";

            switch (urlName) {
                case "VG":
                    urlValue = "http://www.vg.no";
                    break;

                case "Dagbladet":
                    urlValue = "http://www.dagbladet.no";
                    break;

                case "Nettavisen":
                    urlValue = "http://www.nettavisen.no";
                    break;
            }
            view.loadUrl(urlValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            wb1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,  
long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/omAppen"
    android:id="@+id/buttonOmOss"
    android:onClick="visOmAppen"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: **It doesn't work**, is not an issue that someone can solve. Please post the exact error/non required behavior along with the logcat.

Comment: The thing that doesnt work is :  the webview dont want to show the website thats in the value of the string array

Comment: An item in string array cannot have any attributes like `value`. Refer this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selected_url = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    view.loadUrl(selected_url);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

private Button omAppenKnapp;
Spinner spinner;
WebView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new browser());
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selected_url = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    view.loadUrl(selected_url);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Comment: its loadUrl not loafUrl

Comment: and also declare your webView at class level.

Comment: yeah, i tried with loadUrl..
But where should i try it?  should i replace : 

 @Override
        public boolean OverrideURL(WebView view, String Url) {
            view.loadUrl(Url);
            return true;
        }

Comment: put view.loadUrl(selected_url); inside onItemSelected

Comment: stupid question... what do you mean with declare webview at class level? 

private WebViev: ??

Comment: it means outside onCreare just like you declare spinner

Comment: did you get method cannot be resolved at view.loadUrl(String.valueOf(spinner));

Comment: no, i got it at 

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selected_url = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        view.loadUrl(selected_url);

Im very thankfull for your help, this means alot!

Comment: im very gratefull. but i still get the cannot resolve method loadUrl  inside onItemSelected :(

Comment: You are writing  setContentView and super.onCreate()  for two times.remove this for second time

Comment: You are also defining webview for second time remove that also

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745480/cannot-find-symbol-method-loadurlstring

Comment: I have tried various options, thats why maybe somethings are defined several times. Im desperate..

Comment: just keep in mind that you are not defining anything for second time

Comment: Ive added the WebView object in the layout like the post you refered to, but it doesnt help. Do you still want to help me? If not i can understand :'/

Comment: Have to dissapoint again.. still getting the cannot resolve method synbol loadUrl java.lang.string

Comment: as @Prerak Sola said just rename the webview. It will solve your problem

Comment: rename view.loadUrl(urlValue); with wb1.loadUrl((urlValue); inside onItemSelected

Comment: omg do you know how happy i am atm?? im almost crying.. have been strugling for hours with this, and now it works!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String urlName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                String urlValue = "http://www.google.com";

                switch (urlName)
                {
                    case "VG":
                        urlValue ="http://www.vg.no";
                        break;

                    case "Dagbladet":
                        urlValue = "http://www.dagbladet.no";
                        break;

                    case "Nettavisen":
                        urlValue = "http://www.nettavisen.no";
                        break;
                }
                webView.loadUrl(urlValue);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is my android studio broken or something ????? 

https://gyazo.com/f9f068c1f79c254bb341af7bd4d312c0

Comment: Edit your question and post you complete code along with the imports

Comment: https://gyazo.com/99d540c3201ce864b6cbbf4e9adcb1d1
https://gyazo.com/7e2cdcadbd99c5841bd4e08709e95602

Here is my complete code..

Comment: Rename your WebView object to something else. In the `onItemSelected` method, there is an input parameter with the name `view`.

Comment: yes.. just implement it and you will know whether its working or not!

Comment: It didnt do anything mate :(

Comment: Its not possible. Add the code in your question and not as images. I

Comment: Remove `implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` and also the last two overridden methods.

Comment: If it helped you, you can mark the answer as correct so that it will be helpful to others in the future.